# Overflow causes partially visible tag names on /users with long tag names

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, design, users-page

On the `/users` page, the top tags responsible for the bulk of your reputation gains are shown underneath your username and reputation for that selected period. In the instance that your tag names are long this can cause a pretty ugly overflow issue resulting in partially visible tag names, as follows:

[image]

This issue is currently(!) [visible for multiple users on the Arqade users page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=week), showing reputation, filtered down to this current week.